# Pop up Arabic/ Urdu keyboard for edit box input in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad, android-input-method

I am working on application, which will require the user to have an Urdu or Arabic keyboard on screen for input.

The issue is that the Urdu keyboard may or may not be installed on the phone, so how would I pop up an Urdu keyboard? I have no idea whether there's a way to specify input language for edit boxes.

Also, the language setting should work only with my application, default keyboard should not be changed for other apps.

Any ideas?

Mapping of English characters to Urdu characters isn't feasible for me!